# Calling Activity.finish() does nothing

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm having a very strange behavior in my game application. There are two classes - `GameActivity` and `GameManager`. `GameManager` runs all the logic, and `GameActivity` just hosts a `GameManager` instance. Now there's a pause menu and an Exit button inside. Clicking it calls `finish()` on GameManager, which in turn calls the actual `finish()` method on `GameActivity`. And the problem is that the call just does nothing. I've put a bunch of log calls in places like `onPause()`, but neither is getting called. That just seems absolutely weird to me. Will appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: I think we should see code, because from your tell all right.

Comment: @IlyaDemidov, And this is the problem, cause there's nothing more to post than a plain simple call to Activity.finish()..

Comment: Have you checked that the onClickListener (or whatever you're using) is called and attached to the Button properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment: Activity.finish() probably does nothing, try passing the actual context of the GameActivity to the game manager.

```
private Activity gameActivityContext;

//in game activity
onCreate() {
   gameActivityContext = this;
   GameManager mngr = new GameManager(gameActivityContext);
}

//in game manager
....
gameActivityContext.finish();
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was actually able to solve the problem by starting the previos activity with the Intent.FLAG_CLEAR_TOP flag. Can't imagine why finish() did not work, anyway, the problem is solved.

Comment: This flag finishes the activity when navigating away from it. Sometimes it might not be very satisfactory. If that is the use though, then I think you are covered.